# How can I see when my PC was rebooted?

Tags: debian, uptime

How can I see when my PC was rebooted? I need to know the last 10 times.

Comment: What OS is your PC using?

Comment: @DarkHeart.   No need for the pipe to grep.   Use `last reboot`

Comment: last reboot gave me two results! `last reboot
reboot   system boot  4.5.0-2-amd64    Thu Jul 14 18:16   still running
reboot   system boot  4.5.0-2-amd64    Sun Jul  3 21:42   still running
`

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Do you want to post that as an answer? Don't want to rip off your solution. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** As [@fpmurphy1](//unix.stackexchange.com/users/7919/fpmurphy1) mentioned in a [comment](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296285/how-can-i-see-when-my-pc-was-rebooted#comment520156_296285), there's no need for all the runlevel grepping below.
A simple `last reboot -n 10` will do.

---

<strike>last -xF | grep -e 'lvl 2' -e 'lvl 5' | head -10</strike>

`last` is mainly used to check when and for how long a certain user was logged in (also see `lastlog` for that), but the log file it uses (`/var/log/wtmp` by default) also logs system reboots and runlevel changes.

`-x` includes these runlevel changes in the output and `-F` prints the full date and time (instead of an abbreviated form).
The normal multi-user mode is usually runlevel 2, so we `grep` for that and extract the first (i.e. most recent) 10 results.

```
$ last -xF | grep 'lvl 2' | head -10
runlevel (to lvl 2)   4.6.3-040603-gen Sat Jul 16 08:41:02 2016 - Sat Jul 16 11:08:37 2016  (02:27)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   4.6.3-040603-gen Fri Jul 15 14:37:20 2016 - Fri Jul 15 20:58:40 2016  (06:21)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   4.6.3-040603-gen Thu Jul 14 22:50:43 2016 - Thu Jul 14 22:52:07 2016  (00:01)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   4.6.3-040603-gen Thu Jul 14 13:50:13 2016 - Thu Jul 14 22:50:12 2016  (08:59)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   4.6.3-040603-gen Tue Jul 12 13:17:37 2016 - Thu Jul 14 00:06:28 2016 (1+10:48)   
runlevel (to lvl 2)   4.6.3-040603-gen Tue Jul 12 10:21:00 2016 - Tue Jul 12 11:07:47 2016  (00:46)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   4.6.3-040603-gen Mon Jul 11 21:56:36 2016 - Mon Jul 11 23:35:26 2016  (01:38)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   4.6.3-040603-gen Mon Jul 11 07:37:25 2016 - Mon Jul 11 09:25:13 2016  (01:47)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   4.6.3-040603-gen Sun Jul 10 16:40:55 2016 - Sun Jul 10 23:14:01 2016  (06:33)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   4.6.3-040603-gen Fri Jul  8 14:52:26 2016 - Sun Jul 10 13:13:59 2016 (1+22:21)
```

Comment: I get no results at all from that.

Comment: all my debian systems seem to use runlevel 5, but wtmp seems to only go back a couple of weeks,

Comment: @Jasen If the system has been running continously for a long time, your `wtmp` might have been logrotated since the reboot. On Debian, `wtmp` is rotated monthly and the file from the previous month is kept as `wtmp.1`. You can try looking at that one (`last -f /var/log/wtmp.1`), but if your system has been online longer than two months, you won't be getting your last 10 boot times this way.

Comment: @Jasen You're right, runlevel 2 seems to be Ubuntu-specific. I just checked an actual Debian system and it does indeed use runlevel 5. I've updated the search string in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The classic UNIX command for this is `uptime` which knows how long the current kernel has been running and also gives the current load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **# tuptime  -l -S-10** and it will report the date and time of the last 10 events of startup/shutdown.